# Problem with internal variable of a `Module` which returns the solution of an `NDSolve` command. y$25947 → InterpilatingFunction[…]

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction, syntax, scoping

I will try to give a minimal example of my problem. Say I define the following function, spitting out an `NDSolve` result, using `Module`:

```
f[case : True | False] := Module[{x, rhs},

  If[case,
   rhs[x_] = y[x] Cos[x + y[x]],
   rhs[x_] = y[x]
   ];

  NDSolve[{y'[x] == rhs[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]

  ]
```

The argument of `f` thereby specifies the right hand side of the differential equation: If the argument it `True`, the right hand side is `y[x] Cos[x + y[x]]`, if it is `False`, it is just `y[x]`.

Now, the way I defined it above, everything works fine, and the result is displayed as the usual

```
{{y → InterpolatingFunction[...]}}
```

output of `NDSolve`. However `y` is a global variable, so I would like to protect it inside my function by adding `y` to the set of local variables:

```
f[case : True | False] := Module[{x, y, rhs},

  If[case,
   rhs[x_] = y[x] Cos[x + y[x]],
   rhs[x_] = y[x]
   ];

  NDSolve[{y'[x] == rhs[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]

  ]
```

If I run the function now, it would still produce the correct solution curves. However the output is now displayed for example as

```
{{y$25947 → InterpolatingFunction[...]}}
```

where the concrete number after the dollar sign changes every time I execute.

So something is going wrong. I am not sure what, and how to fix it.

Thanks for help!

Comment: "However `y` is a global variable, so I would like to protect it inside my function..."  Just curious, but what problem does `y` being a global variable cause?

Comment: No problem, as long as one keeps the overview of what variables are used inside ones functions. In order of not having to keep this overview, I wanted to make it a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ClearAll[f];
f[case : True | False] := 
 Module[{x, y, rhs}, 
  If[case, rhs[x_] = y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], rhs[x_] = y[x]];
  y /. First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == rhs[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]]
```

Then if you run

```
intp = f[True]
```

you will get an interpolation function you can use elsewhere

```
Plot[intp[x], {x, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

Hope that helps

***Edit to answer question***

The variables that you make local to the module, y in this case, are changed to have a unique number attached to them. This stops them interfering with variables outside the module. If you output the variable then you see how it was formulated within the module.

Comment: I suppose that works, thanks! Do you know by any chance what exactly went wrong? It would be good to understand, so I can avoid making similar mistakes.

Comment: @Britzel I have added a comment to show how it works. Let me know if you need more . You can also look up `Block` and `With` which are variants on `Module` handling internal variables in different manners.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the explanation! Also, I will check `Block` and `With` indeed. I was not aware of those. Cheers!

Comment: With any newer version of Mathematica you could also use `NDSolveValue` which would make your could a bit shorter and probably clearer. It seems to be made for exactly that use-case...

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [formal symbol](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalAndOtherNotation.html#173509264) inside `f` to avoid problems, since it can't be assigned a value.

```
f[case : True | False] := Module[{x, rhs}, 
  If[case, rhs[x_] = \[FormalY][x] Cos[x + \[FormalY][x]], rhs[x_] = \[FormalY][x]];
  NDSolve[{\[FormalY]'[x] == rhs[x], \[FormalY][0] == 1}, \[FormalY], {x, 0, 30}]]

(* trying to break it -- fails! *)
\[FormalY] = 1;
f[True]
(* Set::wrsym Symbol \[FormalY] is Protected. *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Good solution! Thanks a lot!